# HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode

Tags: android, emulation

I have a problem in Android Studio emulator, I've got this message when I run the project

```
 C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools\emulator.exe -avd smth -netspeed full -netdelay none
Creating filesystem with parameters:
Size: 69206016
Block size: 4096
Blocks per group: 32768
Inodes per group: 4224
Inode size: 256
Journal blocks: 1024
Label: 
Blocks: 16896
Block groups: 1
Reserved block group size: 7
Created filesystem with 11/4224 inodes and 1302/16896 blocks
emulator: device fd:940
HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode

emulator: VCPU shutdown request
EAX=e0000011 EBX=00000000 ECX=00000000 EDX=00000000
ESI=00020800 EDI=c0a39000 EBP=00c55003 ESP=0083c000
EIP=c08ad176 EFL=00010002 [-------] CPL=0 II=0 A20=1 SMM=0 HLT=0
ES =0018 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
CS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09b00 DPL=0 CS32 [-RA]
SS =0018 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
DS =0018 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
FS =0018 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
GS =0018 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
LDT=0000 00000000 00000000 00008200 DPL=0 LDT
TR =0020 00001000 00000067 00008b00 DPL=0 TSS32-busy
GDT=     00846300 0000001f
IDT=     00000000 00000000
CR0=e0000011 CR2=008ad16f CR3=008d5000 CR4=00000000
```

build.gardle

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.tasnim.calendar"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 21
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
}
```

I tried run my project using Android 2.3.3 and Android 4.4.4 and I've got this error message in both cases.

Any help please?

Answer (score 4):

I think emulator is crashing when it tries to load HAX, try to download  the latest HAXM driver:
https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager

Also check if there is any update for HAXM  in sdk manager (in Extras).

[image]